# Using strong typing when passing parameters to COM

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a C# program which makes calls to a COM component. The COM methods take parameters of type object and I'm trying to figure a clean way to call the functions.

Say I want to call a method with a signature like `COMObject.GetNodeList(ref object nNodeList)` which returns an array of node ids (i.e. nNodeList would be of an array of `int`), is there some way I can call the function and pass it an `int[]` parameter directly?

At the moment I have to write code like:

```
    private void Update()
    {
        object ids = null;

        ids = new object[this.OSG.GetNodeCount()];
        this.OSG.GetNodeList(ref ids);

        for (int i = 0; i <= ((int[])ids.Count() - 1; i++)
            this.Add(ids[i]);
    }
```

or the compiler complains because of mismatched types. What I really would want to write is this:

```
    private void Update()
    {
        int[] ids = null;

        ids = new int[this.OSG.GetNodeCount()];
        this.OSG.GetNodeList(ref ids);

        for (int i = 0; i <= ids.Count() - 1; i++)
            this.Add(ids[i]);
    }
```

so I don't have to do type conversions all the time.

VB.NET allows me to do it, so surely there must be a way to do this in C# as well?

Comment: You do have some control over the marshaling when you create your own interops; however, based on your example, I wonder if you can't just add int[] idsAsArray = (int[])ids; after your GetNodeList call. VB.NET probably works because the type it's returning is dynamic and loosely bound.

Comment: @Markus - I think you mean _late_ bound?

Comment: Actually, whilst the code above works and compiles, the COM methods do not return a value unless the array passed by ref is of type `int[]`. I'd really like a way of doing this in C#... but maybe VB.NET is the right (only) tool for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like such an idiot. The solution was the dynamic keyword.

```
    private void Update()
    {
        dynamic ids;

        ids = new int[this.OSG.GetNodeCount()];
        this.OSG.GetNodeList(ref ids);

        for (int i = 0; i <= ids.Length - 1; i++)
            this.Add(ids[i]);
    }
```

Obviously the lack of intellisense is a bit of a bummer. For once VB.NET is nicer to use than C#?

Comment: :) No reason for that...every day in code is a new experience. And, if it's not, you're probably in the wrong job. Right, @groverboy?

Comment: With `dynamic` this code uses late binding: in the call to GetNodeList the actual type of ids will be resolved only at runtime, along with security checks, etc. This is slower than early binding, where checks and type resolution occur at compile time. If you want to improve performance don't use `dynamic`, instead initialise `int[] ids = new int[this.OSG.GetNodeCount()];` then typecast ids to the expected type: `object o = (object)ids; this.OSG.GetNodeList(ref o);` But slower performance won't be noticeable if you call GetNodeList only once!

Comment: @Groverboy, yes, it is actually factionally, but noticeably slower when I use dynamic. And that's before I even start applying the method fully. I'll probably go back to early binding even though the code becomes longer. At least for performance critical sections anyway.